# How to get accurate height of label if it contains a NSAttributed String with parts of string in BOLD

Tags: objective-c, ios, height, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I am currently using the following method to get the required height of the label

```
+ (CGFloat) getHeightOfLabel:(NSString *)text ofFontSize:(CGFloat)fontSize withConstraint:(CGSize)constraint
{
    CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontSize] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    return size.height;
}
```

This works in most cases, however, there are some strings which consist a mixture of bold and unbold text which might affect the exact height required in extreme cases.

For example

[image]

Are there any ways to get the accurate height of the label containing this mixture?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how

```
UILabel *labelWithAtributedText = ...
CGSize size = [labelWithAtributedText sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(maxWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX)];
```

Answer (score -2):

I was struggling with this as well. Here are a couple ideas:

1. Use **boldSystemFontOfSize** to calculate the height since it will allow for maximum room (In most cases, this worst well. Some labels will be a little taller than needed but I find it's better than getting cut off.)
2. Calculate the average between **systemFontOfSize** and **boldSystemFontOfSize**

```
+ (CGFloat) getHeightOfLabel:(NSString *)text ofFontSize:(CGFloat)fontSize withConstraint:(CGSize)constraint  
{  
    CGSize size1 = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontSize] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];  
    CGSize size2 = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:fontSize] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];  

    return (size1.height+size2.height)/2;  
}
```

If you don't need the actual height use [label sizeToFit] but I'm assuming you need this height :)